# Runtime Error: Index out of range when attempting to os.StartProcess

Tags: go

I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this:

I have a function setup like this:

```
func (srv *Server) StartServer() {
  // Some stuff to make sure paths are correct

  path := srv.Path + "server.exe"
  var args = []string{
    "ip=" + srv.IP,
    "un=" + srv.Username,
    "pw=" + srv.Password
  }
  proc, err := os.StartProcess(path, args, new(os.ProcAttr))
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

The StartProcess method throws an index out of range.

I'm probably just missing something, but I just can't see it.

Exact error as requested:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
syscall.StartProcess(0xc082052b70, 0x21, 0xc08200a6e0, 0x5, 0x5, 0xc08201dd60, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/syscall/exec_windows.go:322 +0x94c
os.startProcess(0xc082052b70, 0x21, 0xc08200a6e0, 0x5, 0x5, 0xc08200a730, 0x5217e0, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/os/exec_posix.go:45 +0x482
os.StartProcess(0xc082052b70, 0x21, 0xc08200a6e0, 0x5, 0x5, 0xc08200a730, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/os/doc.go:24 +0x79
main.(*Server).StartServer(0x5efae0)
        E:/build_test/SrvMgr.go:85 +0x4e6
main.main()
        E:/build_test/SrvMgr.go:54 +0x141

goroutine 2 [runnable]:
runtime.forcegchelper()
        c:/go/src/runtime/proc.go:90
runtime.goexit()
        c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 3 [runnable]:
runtime.bgsweep()
        c:/go/src/runtime/mgc0.go:82
runtime.goexit()
        c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 4 [runnable]:
runtime.runfinq()
        c:/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:712
runtime.goexit()
        c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1
exit status 2
```

Edit: Link to a simplified play.golang post reproducing it. I'm running go version 1.4.2 win/amd64

http://play.golang.org/p/S6kRLMyd2I

Comment: Can you post the error message you get?

Comment: @icza Will update the OP with that info. Just need to teamviewer my computer at home real quick. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Go runtime for me. Consider making a bug report. Can you simplify the example in a way that you still receive an error? What version of Go are you using?

Comment: @FUZxxl I'm using go1.4.2 windows/amd64. I'll have a look at simplifying it here real quick and see if it still does it.

Comment: @FUZxxl Added a link to a simplified version on golang, obviously it won't run on golang itself though.

Comment: Surely. I can't reproduce your problem on Linux though.

Comment: @FUZxxl Strange, I'll look into filing that in a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you do not set the file descriptors for Stderr and Stdout on your os.ProcAttr. It seems those get set automatically on linux, but you need to set them on windows.

This is a working example:

```
func (srv *Server) StartServer() {
  // Some stuff to make sure paths are correct

  path := srv.Path + "server.exe"
  var args = []string{
    "ip=" + srv.IP,
    "un=" + srv.Username,
    "pw=" + srv.Password
  }
  var attr os.ProcAttr
  attr.Files = []*os.File{nil, os.Stdout, os.Stderr}
  proc, err := os.StartProcess(path, args, &attr)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: On UNIX-like operaitng systems, it's possible to start a program with no file descriptors open. It's merely a convention that file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 are open. It's weird that this is not allowed on Windows. Notice that starting a process with an empty file slice on Linux causes the process to be started with no file descriptors open.

Comment: The documentation says "StartProcess is a low-level interface. The os/exec package provides higher-level interfaces." It's these kinds of details that are handled for you by `os/exec` so unless you have some need to muck with lower level details you should use that instead.

Comment: @DaveC Thanks, I'll have a look at exec again as well.